# UIImageView's content mode changes when scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, sdwebimage, uiviewcontentmode

I have a table view (`SlackTextViewController`) with a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains an `UIImageView` and a `UITextView`. I use `SDWebImage` for caching and setting images.

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"CommentsCell";

    CommentsCell *cell =(CommentsCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:identifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }        

    commentsModel =(CommentsModel *)commentsListArray[indexPath.row];

    if (commentsModel.hasImage) {    
        cell.imageHeight.constant=150;
        cell.photoImageView.hidden = NO;

        NSString *imageUrl = commentsModel.commentImage;
        [cell.photoImageView setShowActivityIndicatorView:YES];
        [cell.photoImageView setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

        cell.photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [cell.photoImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];    
    } else  {
        cell.imageHeight.constant=0;
        cell.photoImageView.hidden = YES;
        cell.textview.text=commentsModel.comments;
        [cell.textview sizeToFit];                
    }

    cell.transform = self.tableView.transform;
    return cell

}
```

When the view controller is opened for the first time, the imageView's content mode is somehow set to `ScaleAspectFit` and when I scroll up and down for a couple of times, the content mode is properly set to `ScaleAspectFill`.

**Initial content mode state:**

[image: Initial content mode state]

**After scrolling up and down some:**

[image: After scrolling up and down some]

**Another weird thing** that happens is, when I present a `UIAlertController`, the content mode of the imageView suddenly animates to `ScaleAspectFill` as you can see in below video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OT3bUR4CR5c&feature=youtu.be

- I haven't changed the content mode to `ScaleAspectFit` anywhere in the code accidentally.
- I checked the view hierarchy to see that there are no changes in the imageView's width and height, and I am not changing its frame anywhere.
- I tried setting the content mode in `prepareForReuse` method of the custom cell.
- I tried setting image in main thread.

None of the above is solving the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a border to your image view so that we could see the bounds? I understand that your position in this situation is that you are innocent and didn't do anything, but there are should be something, table view and cell by default doesn't act like this, neither `SDWebImage`.

Comment: I suspect that, somewhere the image view's frame is being changed, and that's causing the issue.

Comment: @FahriAzimov Added image with border.

Comment: I am also not sure what causes the glitch in the video I attached.

Comment: Very weird. Full code for your custom cell and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` could help a lot.

Comment: Done. I am actually adjusting the height of the imageView via a constraint (`imageHeight`), but that should not affect the content mode.

Comment: What about in nib file? Try to set the `contentMode` to `ScaleAspectFill` in there please.

Comment: I’ve set it everywhere I can. ;)

Comment: cell.transform = self.tableView.transform; remove that line and try again.

Comment: @JRB I removed it and it's still the same.